# get url and add instance to a model with prefilled foreign key :django admin

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin, django-views

I have a page in which each contest is shown in a row. each row contains contest id and link to other model names which have foreign key to contest. like News model:

```
class News(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    time = models.TimeField( default= datetime.datetime.now().time())
    contest = models.ForeignKey(Contest)
```

I want to use admin for adding and changing these models. i want when user clicks on 'News' which has foreign key to contest id=1, it only shows list of News with this value for foreign key. so i use

```
{% for instance in instances %}
                    <tr class="{% cycle 'row1' 'row2' %}">
                        <td>{{ instance.title }}</td>
                        <td>{{ instance.startTime }}</td>
                        <td>{{ instance.timeSpan }}</td>
                        <td>{{ instance.date }}</td>                      
                        <td><a href="/admin/ContestManagement/news/?contest__id__exact={{ instance.id }}">News</a></td>                       
                {% endfor %}
```

now when i click on this link, it shows list of News with this special contest id as i want. now i want to know how can i understand in this template(change_list filtered with contest id), what contest id is in this page to add news to this contest id and what have i do? (because the current url is: /admin/ContestManagement/news/add/
[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]
i tried `{{request}}` in template, but it was empty!! 
thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `{{request}}` is empty you have to add **django.core.context_processors.request** in the **TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS** of your *settings.py*

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-request

Comment: thanks a lot :) I get my answer. And can you please guide me what's the best way to use contest id? I mean now (with your help) i can get contest id in add_form template and i can use this value to set contest field value. but is there a better way? for example do it with django admin functions?